# Downloading SharePoint 2019 monthly patches using a PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, microsoft

I would like to download SharePoint 2019 patches (on-premise) using PowerShell Script.

The Microsoft Update Catalog only has core patches but I want to download language patch as well.

Please let me know if there is way to achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use some automated install\patch scripts as a reference:
[AutoSPSourceBuilder](https://github.com/brianlala/AutoSPSourceBuilder) and [SPPatchify](https://www.spjeff.com/2016/05/16/sppatchify-cu-patch-entire-farm-from-one-script/).
Basically they are using its own xml\csv with direct links to both *sts* and *wssloc* patch files.

You can use them as it is or adapt to your specific needs.
AutoSPSourceBuilder seems to updating its links more often though.